# belongs_to and has_many of the same items

Tags: activerecord

I'm modeling a **lessons** table, the lesson belongs to a user, the teacher and creator of the lesson, and also, the lesson can have many students, which are also users.

So it would be something like this

```
class Lesson < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :users
end
```

I'd like to call the first user **teacher**, and the collection of users **students**, I've read the documentation at http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html but I can't quite find what I want.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should have what you want: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-belongs_to

I think you want the `class_name` option:

```
class Lesson < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :teacher, class_name: "User"
  has_many :students, class_name: "User"
end
```

Comment: Oh, oops, I wrote `belongs_to` instead of `has_many`. Yes, it has the same `class_name` option, so it works the same way.

Comment: Have a look at the above link, section 2.10: the names "subordinates" and "manager" (respectively "teacher" and "students") in the above example are aliases for the User class, so yes, `has_many` will work.

Answer (score 0):

In your current code, all users could be the "owner" (teacher) of a lesson, instead you should have two additional classes "student" and "teacher" both having a 1:1 relation to the "user" class.

This would fit better:

```
class Teacher < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :user
end

class Student < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :user
end

class Lesson < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :teacher
  has_many :students
end
```

Comment: But students can become teachers, and viceversa, all users can create lessons and take other user's lessons

Comment: In that case a student would change its class to "teacher" or vice versa, the user instance would persist, the association would change. If you don't need prefiltering, I would stick to Jeremy Ruten's solution.